# Select properties based on name and fetch the value

Tags: java, reflection

I have the below class with getters and setters.

```
class A{
 private String field1Required;
 private String field2Required;
 private String field3;
 private String field4;
}
```

Suppose in my main program I receive an **Object A** populated as below,

```
field1Required = false;
field2Required=true, 
field3=true; 
field4=false;
```

So I want select only the `field1Required`, `field2Required` and print the values of those properties. How can I achieve it using reflection or any other way?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to print all the fields that contains the word "Required"?

Comment: What is use of class A if there is no setter/getter method or constructor for initializing the object with that properties. Those values will always be set to default.

Comment: @RajaAnbazhagan Yes

Comment: Take a look at `clazz.getDeclaredMethods()` This will give you all declared method objects through reflection from which you can write a loop to check if the method names contains "Required". As simple as that

Comment: In class, you are showing your fields as `String` then in Object A, saying that those have values as `true` or `false` without double quotes, is that the case?

Answer (score 0):

Considering your class has getters and setters defined, you could use something like this to get your results.

```
    A obj = new obj();
        Class clazz = data.getClass();
        Method[] arr = clazz.getDeclaredMethods();
        for (Method method : arr) {
            if (method.getName().contains("get") && 
                    method.getName().contains("Required")) {
                System.out.println(method.invoke(obj));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A a = new A();
    Field fields [] =a.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    for (int i=0;i<fields.length;i++) {
        if (fields[i].getName().contains("Required"))
            {fields[i].setAccessible(true);
           System.out.println(fields[i]);
           System.out.println(fields[i].get(a));}}
    }
```